# Rotation of Rigid body

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, rotational-kinematics

How to prove the equation (4.14)

$$ a_{ij} a_{ik} = \delta_{jk} $$

from the equation (4.13)

$$ x_i' x_i'  = x_i x_i $$

[image: The Kinematics of Rigid Body Motion]

With summation convention I found it very easy.
But, using summation I am not able to prove the relation.
Please, Somebody help me.

Ref: Classical Mechanics (Goldstein) (3rd ed) (Chapter 4, Sec-4.2)

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest you to read [the definition of Cartesian coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system#Two_dimensions).

It's then come clear the question $(a_{ij}x_j)(a_{ik}x_k)=x_ix_i$, which refereed to equation 4.11 (not shown). But mathematically, it's simply a preservation of $L_2$ norm (square), which comes the product of $a(s)$.

One can use equation to multiple them out. But in short, just imagine an arrow rotating around in two different directions, and in order for the product of those two representations to be the same, the coefficient had to be one. (Something, something triangle.)